# How to use HashMap data in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I count the same value with *HashMap* (says `hasmap`), but how to display key and value of the *HashMap* in *RecyclerView*?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hasmap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
    JSONObject List_data_kecamatan = data.getJSONObject(i);

    String nama_kecamatan = List_data_kecamatan.getString("dapil_kecamatan");

    int count = 0;
    if (hasmap.containsKey(nama_kecamatan)){
        count = hasmap.get(nama_kecamatan)+1;
        hasmap.put(nama_kecamatan, count);
    }else {
        hasmap.put(nama_kecamatan, 1);
    }

}
```

I Using JSON Object as key in `hasmap`.

Comment: Initialize `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>()` and add `arrayList.add(hasmap);` then pass this list to `RecyclerView`

Comment: you want to show in the same recyclerview or different. If the same recyclerview, then you want to show key and value in the same item or different item.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking something like:

```
public class MyRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private HashMap<String, String> mData;
    private ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> mActualData;

    public MyRVAdapter(HashMap<String, String> mData) {
        this.mData = mData;
        mActualData = new ArrayList<>(mData.size());
        mData.forEach((s, s2) -> mActualData.add(new Pair<>(s, s2)));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, holder, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(
                String.format("%s - %s", mActualData.get(position).first, mActualData.get(position).second)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mActualData.size();
    }
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mTextView;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView)itemView;
    }
}
```

So this will convert the HashMap into an ArrayList of Key Value Pairs (the `.forEach` will only work on API 24+; swap out with an Iterator if you need lower version support).

You would then use the `setAdapter` method for the `RecyclerView` in your layout.